# Problem removing row in datatable while enumerating

Tags: c#, datatable

I get the following error while I try to delete a row while looping through it.

C#: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

I've been doing some research for a while, and I've read some similar posts here, but I still haven't found the right answer.

```
foreach (DataTable table in JobsDS.Tables)
{

  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
  {
    if (row["IP"].ToString() != null && row["IP"].ToString() != "cancelled")
    {
        string newWebServiceUrl = "http://" + row["IP"].ToString() + "/mp/Service.asmx";
        webService.Url = newWebServiceUrl;
        string polledMessage = webService.mpMethod(row["IP"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString());

        if (polledMessage != null)
        {
            if (polledMessage == "stored")
            {               
                removeJob(id);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using `foreach`, use a reverse `for` loop:

```
for(int i = table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
    //do your stuff
}
```

Removing the row indeed modifies the original collection of rows. Most enumerators are designed to explode if they detect the source sequence has changed in the middle of an enumeration - rather than try to handle all the weird possibilities of `foreach`ing across something that is changing and probably introduce very subtle bugs, it is safer to simply disallow it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify a collection inside of a `foreach` around it.

Instead, you should use a backwards `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove Elements from a loop on a list of Elements, the trick is to use a for loop, start from the last Element and go to the first Element.

In your example :

```
int t_size = table.Rows.Count -1;

for (int i = t_size; i >= 0; i--)
{
   DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
   // your code ...
}
```

Edit : not quick enough :)

Comment: @SLaks i dont think it has any more or less of a point than your comment does

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you depend on the order that you process the rows and a reverse loop does not work for you. You can add the rows that you want to delete to a List and then after you exit the foreach loop you can delete the rows added to the list. For example,

```
foreach (DataTable table in JobsDS.Tables) 
{ 
  List<DataRow> rowsToRemove = new List<DataRow>();
  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) 
  { 
    if (row["IP"].ToString() != null && row["IP"].ToString() != "cancelled") 
    { 
        string newWebServiceUrl = "http://" + row["IP"].ToString() + "/mp/Service.asmx"; 
        webService.Url = newWebServiceUrl; 
        string polledMessage = webService.mpMethod(row["IP"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString()); 

        if (polledMessage != null) 
        { 
            if (polledMessage == "stored") 
            {                
                //removeJob(id); 
                rowsToRemove.Add(row);
            } 

        } 
    } 
  }
  rowsToRemove.ForEach(r => removeJob(r["ID"].ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `removeJob(id)` changes one of the IEnumerables your enumerating (`table.Rows` or `JobsDS.Tables`, from the name of the method I guess it would be the latter), maybe via DataBinding.

I'm not sure the backwards `for` is going to work directly because it seems you're removing an element enumerated in the outer foreach from within the inner foreach. It's hard to tell without more info about what happens in removeJob(id).